# Как отключить/удалить/убрать StatusBar (есть root права)

Tags: android, root

Вот что я уже пробовал

Спрятать статус бар через adb [ссылка1](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/hide-navigation-status-bars-your-galaxy-s8-for-even-more-screen-real-estate-no-root-needed-0177297/)
[ссылка2](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/disable-heads-up-notifications-any-android-no-root-needed-0182247/)

[Офф-документация](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status?hl=ru)

[С помощью приложения full!screen](https://android-manual.org/soft-review/hide-nav-panel)

Проблема в том что начиная с версии (вроде) android 6 (api 23) statusBar можно вытащить свайпом вниз, возможно если пойти в обратную сторону и как то заблокировать статус бар что бы он не скрывался, тогда его программно скроет  (как до версии api 23)

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

но и это непонятно как реализовать.

Есть какие то идеи? Рут есть.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Вы хотите чтобы в вашем приложении вообще не было статусбара?

Comment: да именно такого результата добиваюсь.

Comment: Укажите стиль `Fullscreen` и тогда статусбар будет по свайпу доступен

Comment: мне не нужно что бы он был доступен! Вы почему то не правильно поняли. Мне нужно убрать статус бар, что бы его вообще не было, что бы его нельзя было вызвать/открыть, мне всё равно какими способами, главное не дать пользователю вызвать статусбар. Понимаете? Если не понимате нажмите на ссылку на офф документацию там второй рисунк, этот тот эфект который нужен, но если сделать по данному примеру, то статус бар всёравно можно вызвать свайпом, а мне нужно запретить его открывать.

Comment: Ага. Тогда невозможно. Даже если можно то вызвать его один фиг получится, если постараться. При получении уведомления он сам вылазиет, а так как это SystemUI вы не в праве контролировать его касания.

Comment: Я все сразу понял) просто убедился что вам фуллскрина мало

Comment: Знаете что вы можете? Есть способ закрыть шторку через рефлексию. Что если в цикле ее постоянно закрывать? Тогда ее не будут успевать открывать

Comment: Совет конечно хороший но это тоже не работает. android открывает шторку, а потом её закрывает, то есть пока анимация открытия не доработает до конца анимация закрытия не начинается. Умный пользователь может успеть открыть её и на что то клацнуть. Я успеваю.

Comment: Ну я думаю что варианта полностью рабочего не будет никогда. В андроиде и обычные вещи трудно делать правильно, а тут необычные) Запретить открытие статусбара полностью и на 100% уверенно можно лишь став системным приложением (именно так работает SetupWizard - мастер настройки)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блокировка статус бара (полностью и на 100%) реализована в режиме Kiosk Mode начиная с Lollipop (API 21 )

Офф. документация https://developer.android.com/work/cosu

Answer (score 1):

Напишите  в вашей активности:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

}

Comment: лёгкий свайп вниз и статус бар появляется. То что вы указали, у меня встроено в самой теме, см. xml блок кода

Answer (score 0):

Варианта полностью рабочего не будет никогда. В андроиде и обычные вещи трудно делать правильно, а тут необычные.

Запретить открытие статусбара полностью и на 100% уверенно можно лишь сделав приложение системным (именно так работает SetupWizard - мастер настройки)